# Disable image in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to disable images in Chromedriver with Javascript ( Node.js )? I couldn't find a proper answer to this question anywhere!

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would like to load the pages with Selenium ChromeDriver without download the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do realise this question is quite old, but still - it is the first Google search result for the `node chromedriver disable images` query. So I decided to give it a go anyway.

I don't know the exact setup the OP was trying to use, so I'll refer to my own. I'm using `nightwatch.js` with pre-built Selenium running `chromedriver`. In my `nightwatch.conf.js` file I have the following setup for the `chromedriver`:

```
module.exports = {  
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      ...
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "chromeOptions": {
          "args": ["disable-web-security"],
          "prefs": {
            "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The setup above works with

```
"chromedriver": "^2.21.2",
"selenium-server": "^2.53.0"
```

and is running Chrome 51.0.2704.84 stable.

I hope that helps someone, as I lost about 3 hours trying to come up with this solution.